# invisible note in Gregorio

Tags: gregorio

Is there a way to make an invisible note in Gregorio?

I'm trying to use abovelinetext to put some text before the music starts, but it seems to need a note to attach to.  I thought if I could attach it to an invisible note, that might work.

Comment: As always on this site your chances of getting an answer largely increase if you post a complete minimal example.

Comment: Can you add an example of the desired output? Did you check the gabc, abc-notation or nabc documentation? This is a problem, which is rather related to that than LaTeX itself. Maybe you should ask it in the music theory forum on stack exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `()` in the gabc, and did it not do the trick? That’s the standard notation for an empty syllable, and I know that it accepts score text like asterisks that are followed by a new word with neumes. But I can’t seem to get it to work with above-lines text.

So, I’d attach the alt text to the first syllable of actual words, e.g. `Di<alt>Celebrant</alt>(gh)` is how to get the first syllable with its abovelinestext as in the Liber Usualis for the first antiphon of Sunday Vespers.

Comment: thanks for the help.  it's not quite what i need, though.  i need the above line text to come -before- the first note.  in that particular piece, i included an ison, and i wanted the word 'ison:' before the first note which had a drone note attached to it.  i realize what i'm trying to do is not typically done in chant scores.  i was debating whether to just use  standard music notation, but the chant notation felt more natural for this particular song.  i ended up just making a footnote in latex, but i would like to know how to do this for the future.